# using posthreadmessage() from different threads

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

i am not quite sure whether this is the correct way to do this (im a hobbyist). I would like to post messages to a worker thread which loops GetMessage() and depending on the message does something. I understand i have to use posthreadmessage() with the handle of that worker thread.

Here is my question:

Can i use

```
PostThreadMessage(idWorkerThread, WM_COMMAND, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)0))
```

from multiple different threads? I understand that that might cause writes of messages into the Worker threads message queue at the same time from different threads. Is that a problem or is it fine? Essentially i want a N->1 inter-thread communication.

Comment: Just to add to what Pete posted, there is no need to worry if OS calls on Windows, or any other multitasker, are thread-safe.  They are, by definition.  If they were not the OS would blow up so quickly that you would never see your desktop. The only exceptions are obscure ones in subsystems like setting process  debugging hooks.  Mainstream kernel calls like PostThreadMessage are 100% thread-safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostThreadMessage is thread safe so you'll be fine.  Its a good way of doing it.  The other option is to have the thread wait on an event or condition variable and have functions to push events to a queue with appropriate synchronisation.